# StackOverflowError while Task compileDebugJavaWithJavac at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.isDynamic

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, androidx, android-databinding

When I built my project with "gradlew assembleDebug" cmd, these errors would occur. I don't know what mistakes I made. Hoping someone could help me.

Stacktrace:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':train:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.isDynamic(Expr.java:351)
at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.isAnyChildDynamic(Expr.java:358)
at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.isDynamic(Expr.java:351)
at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.isAnyChildDynamic(Expr.java:358)
```

Gradle: gradle-5.5.1-bin.zip

Android Gradle plugin: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4

build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
  enabled = true
}
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.8.0"
  annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
  compile 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0'
  compile 'androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0@aar'
  compile 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0@aar'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: Upgraded AGP to 4.0 from 3.5.4.